# MySQL partitioning by table rows

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning, database-partitioning

I create a table as below

```
CREATE TABLE `Archive_MasterLog` (
  `LogID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LogDate` DATETIME NULL,
  `AssessorName` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `TblName` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LogID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Index_72491D22_3806_4A01` (`LogID`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I want to **partitioning this table by number of rows of table** ==> every of 100K rows will create a new partition.

How can do it from MySQL?

Comment: I think the closest you can come is by range partitioning on `LogId`.  This is not perfect, because the values are not 100% guaranteed to have no holes, but it is probably fine for most purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the frequently of data. Some months or weeks we have more than 2M rows/month but others month we have less than 10K rows. I reviewed the data and found that the we should partition by LogID

The reasion also comes from the customer. They don't want to change the the key of table.

Here's my solution

```
CREATE TABLE `ULPAT`.`MasterLog` (
  `LogID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LogDate` DATETIME NULL,
  `AssessorName` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `TblName` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LogID`),

  INDEX `LogID` (`LogID`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
PARTITION BY HASH(mod(ceiling(LogID*0.0000005), 400))
PARTITIONS 400;
```

I think this is not the best solution but work for me.

Thanks

Comment: This solution not work for MySQL 5.5 or higher. The meessage is "Error Code: 1564. This partition function is not allowed"

Comment: You have a redundant index -- A `PRIMARY KEY` is an index; remove the `INDEX(LogID)`.

Comment: 400 partitions is a lot -- and it leads to inefficiencies.

Comment: `HASH` partitioning is useless.

Comment: @RickJames: Please let me know why **HASH** partitioning is useless

Comment: "Partition pruning" does not speed up queries any more than a good index.  Nor does partitioning speed up `INSERTs`.  Please show us what query you think will be enhanced by partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

Why?  You will probably gain no benefits from `PARTITIONing`.

Will you be purging old data?  If so, the partition on LogDate.  Then we can discuss how to purge.

You have two keys on the same pair of rows, keep the `PRIMARY KEY`, toss the `UNIQUE` key.

You have an index on `RecordID`, but that column does not exist??

Comment: Hi Rick, I update the question to remove RecordID. But I think you're right, I should partition by LogDate